# Ensure only one job runs on rails SuckerPunch/Celluloid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, celluloid, sucker-punch

I have a simple SuckerPunch job, I am trying to make it so only one job runs at any given time. Struggling to work it out tried playing with Celluloid and Ruby concurrency

What I have

```
DataChangeJob.new.async.perform
```

with

```
class DataChangeJob
  include SuckerPunch::Job
  def perform
    value = Random.rand
    SuckerPunch.logger.info ("starting #{value}")
    sleep(5)
    SuckerPunch.logger.info ("running data change #{value}")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define to have only one worker, that would achieve what you want imho. By default SuckerPunch assumes two workers. So explicitly define 1 as follows:

```
class DataChangeJob
  include SuckerPunch::Job
  workers 1

  def perform
    value = Random.rand
    SuckerPunch.logger.info ("starting #{value}")
    sleep(5)
    SuckerPunch.logger.info ("running data change #{value}")
  end
end
```

You are making me curious: why do you need this constraint?

[UPDATE] While SuckerPunch does allow 1 worker, celluloid does not. So you are back to using mutexes.

```
class DataChangeJob
  include SuckerPunch::Job

  def initialize
    @@mutex = Mutex.new 
  end

  def perform
    @@mutex.lock
    begin
      value = Random.rand
      SuckerPunch.logger.info ("starting #{value}")
      sleep(5)
      SuckerPunch.logger.info ("running data change #{value}")
    end
  ensure
    @@mutex.unlock
  end   
end
```

This is just a quick write-up. Assuming all jobs are instances of `DataChangeJob`, we use a mutex on class level. Locking the mutex will attempt to lock the mutex, and wait until the mutex is free. The `ensure`
block will make sure we `unlock` the mutex no matter what happened.

This will make sure only one `DataChangeJob` can run at a time. A bit defeating the advantage celluloid gives you :)

Comment: Tried that, there is a validation rule to ensure you have at least two workers. I might be trying to make Suckerpunch do something it isn't intended to do. But my goal is build an api that fires off a 'job' however I need to ensure if the job is running that no other jobs run. (I don't actually care if those other jobs run again)

Comment: Mmmmm that is weird. In the code i only see an exception if `num_workers < 1`. What error do you get?

Comment: I get ArgumentError: minimum pool size is 2
 from /home/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@my/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/pool_manager.rb:14:in `initialize'

Comment: Ok: that error comes from celluloid, the library suckerpunch uses. I edited my answer and propose to use a mutex instead.